# RequireJS optimize using r.js and Uglify

Tags: requirejs, uglifyjs, r.js, uglifyjs2

We have a multiple file/module based application. We are using r.js with uglify2 to optimize the build. It current does whitespace removal and minification which is great.

**Requirement** - Can we somehow obfuscate function names used in a file such that other RequireJS modules which are including this custom file do not break and continue to use the "obfuscated" function names?

Many thanks!

Comment: The process of minification renames local variables, so it obfuscates most of your code. But a module's API should never be obfuscated... How do you plan on communicating with it then?

Comment: Thanks @Salketer. I agree. The app is not open for any public api access. If the obfuscated API names can be somehow preserved in the dependent modules, wouldn't it work?

Comment: I am not aware of any obfuscation tool that does it so you would need to build one I guess... And really, what is so bad about having function names in plain? "getClientData()" does not help someone a lot in engineering your logic... Also, obfuscation will only slow theft only by a bit... Maybe you'd like the community's answers on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766834/how-do-i-protect-javascript-files

Comment: Actually, although I did look up docs and references, I wasn't aware if any option to achieve what I intended exists or didn't. If there was any, I wanted to enable it and I was looking for feedback from people like you. So, thanks a lot :)

Comment: you're welcome. What we do here at work is simply use client-side javascript for display logics, and keep our real knowledge and power server-side... And we use copyrights!

Comment: In our case, the app works as an add-on on a closed customer platform. So, it is a pure JS application with proprietary logic. We are using copyrights but also looking for a way which can help minimize the code inspections.