# How to protect my angular application?

Tags: angularjs, ddos

I have created an angular application which uses web services to fetch data from my backend and also implementing other logical data based on user.

Since it is a client side application, the code will be visible for anyone and my logical functionalities. I am afraid that it is possible that anyone can find a loophole in my application.

Even if I minified my js files, there are many tools available to unminify it.

So is there any possible way to hide my js files from browser or some other way to avoid reading my code?

Comment: Don't worry, nobody wants to steal your client side code. Unless you're trying to obfuscate security problems?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution is you cant hide the javascript code from inspect. The maximum possible method is to minifiy the and uglify the code to make the code un readable. but still there are some other methods to hack it. Please look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766834/how-do-i-protect-javascript-files) for more details.