# Converting iMacros code to Exe or Other?

Tags: javascript, c#, vbscript, imacros

I have created a macro using iMacros & I am curious about is there any way to make its .iim file as  .exe or some other stand alone file to hide the source of script code from others?

Comment: Not sure how that would look like, would it have its own integrated browser?

Comment: no i would like to see it on chrome firefox or any major web browser

Comment: So you want some kind of executable that runs on any browser, but hides the source code? I'm sorry, but that's only JS in my experience. For the rest I think you're asking something impossible.

Comment: do java script give protection to code ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766834/how-do-i-protect-javascript-files