# Counterexample -- hiding javascript source files

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, information-hiding

Trying to view the source code for github.*your_company*.com/stafftools/reports/dormant_users.js.

[image]

When I go to the link, it simply downloads a `.csv` file immediately, with no activity in the Chrome DevTools Network tab. I have tried disabling javascript, cURLing and so forth but nothing works.

Really surprised since from every SO post I've come across, they say it is impossible to hide the source code for `.js` files. 
[How do I protect javascript files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766834/how-do-i-protect-javascript-files)
Just thinking that this would be a really informative counter-example

Comment: They can name the file whatever they want, and it's not a `<script>`'s `src`, just a `data-url` in a `button`. The fact that you found some random file that ends in *.js but is actually a csv doesn't mean one can hide script files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I obfuscate (protect) JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscate-protect-javascript)

Comment: So you're saying it's actually a .csv? Why name it .js then?

Comment: @element_j you cannot hide javascript code, you can make it difficult to read, but you cannot hide it. try to read the provided answers a bit more thoroughly.