# Is there any way to hide or obfuscate schema json-ld?

Tags: hide, obfuscation, schema.org, json-ld

On my webpage I have a standard JSON-LD schema that holds A LOT of data. Is there any way to prevent or make it harder to read for an average user in the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove spacing and new lines. It has to stay machine readable, which I think means you can't obfuscate the actual text or property names.

I guess you could have it stored in another obfuscated format and have JavaScript generate the readable version. But then, anyone checking the rendered html will see it as it is. And it will limit the systems that can read it.

Another idea is to detect if it's a normal user and not provide the structured data to them. They don't need it. But that's cloaking and may annoy Google.

Comment: I'd add on that if the structured data is being used for SEO purposes, then it might be worth re-considering the entire approach. If there's data you have in JSON-LD that you want to "hide" - but that data isn't actual content on the page itself, I don't believe there will be much SEO benefit to it (if any at all).

Answer (score 1):

### Don’t mark up content that is not visible to readers of the page

One of **google Google structured data Quality guidelines** is to give the users the content you describe in your JSON-LD (So the idea of **hiding** or make this data harder to read for "normal users" does not make sense).

> **Don’t mark up content that is not visible to readers of the page.** For
>   example, if the JSON-LD markup describes a performer, the HTML body
>   should describe that same performer. Google Quality guidelines 
>   https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/sd-policies

By the way, "normal/average users" won't inspect your HTML source code (And developers have nothing to do with this specific JSON-LD information either).

### Protect-javascript

If you insist read topics related to **"protect-javascript"** (This issue not related to schema JSON-LD):

- [How can I obfuscate (protect) JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscate-protect-javascript)
- [How do I protect javascript files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766834/how-do-i-protect-javascript-files)
- [Protect your JavaScripts from "view source"](http://lee-le.com/#!blog-2012-12-06)